# What are the advantages and disadvantages of installing an operating system through network?

Tags: network, windows, linux

**Netboot** is a technology that allows a computer to boot through the network, instead of starting on a hard drive, USB stick or DVD, it connects to a remote server to retrieve a disk image to start. 
It is widely used in companies to install an operating system in a few minutes.

It is useful for testing some distributions under Windows or Linux, without losing time to burn several CD.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of installing an operating system through network and is that Secure?

Comment: Booting over the net every time is probably even more common than installing (only) over the net. Main advantage: easier maintenance. And for Linux, making flash drive installers etc. is not hard; no need to waste CDs.

Comment: Also read http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64915/what-are-the-biggest-security-concerns-on-pxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantages are various:

1. You can save a lot of bandwidth.
2. You can customize installs with SPECIFICS. For example, if you have multiple departments, with multiple needs, you could create specific images for specific departments. E.g., a system with network specific tools for say, those who work in a NOC. System with say graphics applications for a marketing/graphics department.
3. Another benefit is it makes things simple to upgrade/update from a single source versus: "Oh someone forgot to mark this CD/DVD/USB" From a security standpoint, the biggest benefit is you control what is installed from the ISO level.
4. You also minimize having to run the risk of allowing a "boot from USB/DVD" rogue images from being introduced.